# Typescript intellisense issue in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I have typescript Intellisence issue in Angular 12 project and when i edit or open `.ts` file in Visual Studio 2019 the code color truning into white color.It behave like nothing happend in edited `.ts` file also attached an image.
After that it is not showing any syntax error and not showing Intellisense.i am suffering from this issue since last one month.i have latest version of Visual Studio 2019.
**This issue is only with .ts files.**

i have
Visual Studio 2019 Version :  **16.11.7**  
and TypeScript Version: **4.3.5**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue when I upgraded angular to 12 and also upgraded Visual Studio 2019 to 16.11.10 but the problem still remains. Whenever I type something in typescript file all font colors are turned into white and i am not able to get the actual theme color till 5-10 mins (someties more). It really hampers my productivity and my day to day work. Today I tried one step and it almost resolved my issue.

Below Resolution worked for VS 2019 16.11.10 And Angular 12.

1. Just remove (SHIFT+DEL) node_modules folder
2. Re-Install the node packages (npm install)
3. Rebuild the project or solution in VS2019.
4. Now , whenever I type i can see the intellisense